# Will an electronic air filter harm my furnace?

Tags: hvac, air-filter

If I install a furnace-mounted, electronic air filter, like [this one](http://www.sears.com/shc/s/p_10153_12605_SPM246739913P?sid=IDx20101019x00001a&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=SPM246739913),

[image: LakeAir International, Inc. LAD-2214AF Furnace Mounted Electronic Air Cleaner - Single Cell Assembly - Silver Cabinet Finish]

will it harm my furnace due to reduced air flow?  How will I know if it reduces air flow too much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to find a unit that can match the required intake air flow of the furnace.

### Estimating required air flow.

To estimate the required amount of air the furnace needs, you'll have to know what type of furnace you have, and how many [BTUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_thermal_unit) the furnace is rated for.  Once you have this information, you'll divide the furnaces rated BTU value by 10,000.

`100,000 BTU / 10,000 = 10`

Next you'll multiply that value by the CFM/10,000 BTU value for your type of furnace.

- Natural Draft Furnace = 100 CFM/10,000 BTU.
- Induced Draft Furnace = 130 CFM/10,000 BTU.
- Condensing Furnace = 150 CFM/10,000 BTU.

`130 * 10 = 1300 CFM (Cubit feet per minute)`

So if you had a 100,000 BTU induced draft furnace, you'd need a filter with at least an output of 1300 CFM.

As the filter gets dirty, air flow will naturally be restricted. Because of this, you'll want to choose a filter system with a higher CFM rating than you need. In our example above we wouldn't want to get a unit that is rated at 1300 CFM, we'd want one rated somewhere closer to 1400 or 1500 CFM.

### Measuring Air Flow

You can determine the actual air flow using a handheld [Anemometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer), like this one

[image]

Start by measuring the area of the duct (Length * Width). Next measure the air speed using the anemometer (ft/min). Finally multiply the area of the duct by the air speed.

`(20" * 25" = 500 sqin.) / 144) = 3.47 sqft.`
`3.47 sqft. * 375 ft/min = 1301.25 CFM`

To determine if the air filter is restricting air flow, calculate the CFM both with and without the filter connected.

### Watching for signs of reduced flow.

If you notice any of the following problems after installation, you likely have restricted the air flow too much.

- Furnace has trouble producing a flame, or flame is small.
- Furnace constantly overheats.
- Furnace struggles to keep up with heating demand.
- Output air flow is weak and/or cold.

Comment: In addition to that goal, you need to keep it clean, as dirty filters make for low CFM. Of course that is a requirement for ANY filter.

Comment: Thanks!  I wanted to be careful to not screw up my furnace.